After implementing UniswapV3 swap logic in Web3.py, I get a lot of logic errors saying "execution reverted: SPL"
I tried to do a Swap on UniswapV3 with the following code in Web3.py.
As a flow, output the value of amount_out_min in quoteExactInputSingle function -> get the pool impact after the swap in sqrt_price_x96_after -> specify the value in amount_out_min with slippage considered from the output value.
The swap was attempted with the function executeInputSingle.
amount_in = w3.to_wei(0.001, "ether") 
slippage = 0.05

amount_out = quoter_contract.functions.quoteExactInputSingle(
    weth_address,
    dai_address,
    500,
    amount_in,
    0
).call()

print(f"Expected amount out: {amount_out}")

amount_out_actual = amount_out / 10**18
print(f"Actual amount out: {amount_out_actual}")

amount_out_min = int(amount_out * 0.999)
print(f"Minimum amount out: {amount_out_min}")

sqrt_price_x96_after = quoter_contract.functions.quoteExactInputSingle(
    weth_address,
    dai_address,
    500,
    amount_in,
    0
).call()

print(f"sqrtPriceX96After: {sqrt_price_x96_after}")

balance_weth = w3.eth.get_balance(my_address)
print(f"WETH balance: {w3.from_wei(balance_weth, 'ether')} WETH")

balance_eth = w3.eth.get_balance(my_address)
print(f"ETH balance: {w3.from_wei(balance_eth, 'ether')} ETH")

tx = router_contract.functions.exactInputSingle(
    (
        weth_address,
        dai_address,
        500,
        my_address,
        amount_in,
        amount_out_min,
        0,
        int(time.time()) + 60 * 60
    )
).build_transaction({
    "from": my_address,
    "nonce": w3.eth.get_transaction_count(my_address)
})

gas_price = w3.eth.gas_price
gas_limit = w3.eth.estimate_gas(tx)

print(f"Gas Price: {gas_price}")
print(f"Gas Limit: {gas_limit}")

tx['gasPrice'] = gas_price
tx['gas'] = gas_limit

log
Expected amount out: 3215020960852153445
Actual amount out: 3.2150209608521534
Minimum amount out: 3208590918930448896
sqrtPriceX96After: 3215020888790644707
WETH balance: 0.002 WETH
ETH balance: 0.002 ETH

web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: ('execution reverted: SPL', '0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000353504c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')

I honestly don't know what is causing this, so I would like to know!

Some quoter examples here if it is any help.
